# IC sheaf of certain explicit variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, perverse-sheaves, intersection-cohomology

Let $n,m$ be two positive integers. Let $Z$ denote the closed subvariety
in $\mathbb A^n \times \mathbb A^m$
given by the equation $x_1...x_n=y_1...y_m$.

QUESTION: What is the stalk (with the action of Frobenius) of the IC
sheaf of $Z$ at the point (0,....0)?

When n=m=2 you get 3-dimensional quadratic cone and the stalk is
cohomology of $\mathbb P^1$ (up to the corresponding shift and Tate twist).
But I don't know what happens for higher $n,m$.

Note that the stalk in this case is the same as the global intersection cohomology.

Answer (score 2):

It's a toric variety, for which intersection cohomology is computed algorithmically, see e.g. De Catldo's lectures.

Comment: Could I ask where I can find De Catldo's lectures? I only found his arXiv article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.3497.pdf

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03642